# How can you make Ledger Nano wallet work with Galleon or Tezbox Seedphrase?

Tags: ledger, wallets, tezbox, galleon

does someone know the answer to this:

1)  You have a tezbox/galleon wallet with a seedphrase. You do not want to use this wallet anymore and instead use only Ledger. Can you take your seedphrase of the tezbox/galleon wallet and put it into Ledger, and your tezzies will appear on Ledger (even though the seedphrase you use was not generated by Ledger)?

2)  How does this restore process work, anything special to know about (eg derivation path etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but in theory it should work as long as you use the same derivation path.

However, if you are migrating to the ledger because you want to secure your funds more, then you shouldn't use the same seedphrase that you used on your computer. Instead, you should create a completely new seedphrase with the Ledger or AirGap (offline device) and then send the funds to the new address.

Comment: thx. And what about vice versa? Do you know for sure if you can take the seedphrase generated in Ledger and input it into Galleon/Tezbox, and restore your funds there`

Comment: Again, it _should_ work, but I haven't tried it. The seedphrases are all constructed by using the same standard (as far as I know). So the only difference is the derivation path. But you can easily verify it by creating a dummy mnemonic (without ever putting funds on it) on your ledger and then try to import it in a wallet and see if you get the same address.